# Flutter / modal_bottom_sheet - constrain width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm reviewing the Flutter 'modal_bottom_sheet' package,  and I'm wondering if there is a way to set the maximum width of a modal bottom sheet?

In my case, this is a web app, so I don't want the popup modal to take the full browser width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a constraint

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
     maxWidth: 500              
  ),
  builder: 
)
```